# JWT access token and refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm trying to implement authentication/authorization using JWT tokens. Now I have webapp and two services. When user authenticates in webapp (username/password) I'll also obtain JWT access and refresh token from OAuth2 server. Access token validity is 15minutes, refresh token is valid forever.

Now if user does some action then webapp will call service1 with JWT token. Service1 then authenticates/authorize user and schedule task to execute after 1 hour and stores JWT token.
What happens after one hour when service1 will try to call service2? Token is expired and service1 doesn't have refresh token, so it won't work.

Well more exactly client in service1 before actually making call to service2 will find out that token is expired and will redirect request to OAuth2 server to authenticate user.

How to avoid this? Custom grant type so I can ask for new access token without user password? Or sending refresh token with access token to service1?

I'm definitely missing something...

Comment: Why does Service2 need to have the access token before performing the scheduled task? Do you have a possibility to pass an ID token (from OpenID Connect) along with the access token?

Comment: service2 doesn't technically need anything. It's oauth2 secured resource (same as service1), so that's why service1 is sending - relaying access token (well it's not cause it expired). I don't have full implementation yet, I'm just trying to wrap my head around this problem. OpenID connect and id_token might be the missing link. I'll have to find out more about ID token lifecycle and expiration.

Comment: If the Service2 just takes and executes scheduled tasks, I would probably check the required access token scope just in Service1 when it's adding the task to the scheduler. Service2 could trust that the scheduler contains just authorized tasks. You could append an ID token to the task, if Service2 wanted to know who requested the task.

Comment: Sounds ok. Is there a way to refresh ID token, without user password? If service1 task executes for a long time or it's supposed to executed far away in future...Data in ID token may be obsolete, user could be disabled/deleted. I know that service1 can ask for new access token (if expired) using implicit/client_credentials grant before calling service2, but how about id token?